# Is it possible to send file contents to a GNU Screen session?

Tags: serial-port, communication, gnu-screen

I'm connecting to a development board over a serial port like so...

```
screen /dev/ttyUSB0 9600
```

I'm connected to a [bootloader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootloader) now, and it is asking me to send a file in [SREC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SREC_(file_format)) format.  I have the file, but how can I send it over the [Screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) session?

Comment: I suppose you could try loading that image into a text editor and paste it into the screen session. hopefully there's no ^A chars in there to really screw things up.

Comment: No, these are big files.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

GNU Screen has a command called *readreg* which you can use to read a file into a register. After a register is filled with data you can paste that data using the *paste* command.

## Inside Screen

Inside Screen, you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>:</kbd> to execute a command. Then you simply write and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
readreg p /path/to/thefile
```

After you have executed the command, you should see a message saying *Slurped X character into buffer*.

You can then paste the data in that buffer by again pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>:</kbd>, then write and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
paste p
```

*Note: p is the name of the register*

**And you're done.**

## Outside Screen

You could also execute the commands outside the Screen session using the `-X` option. If you have a Screen session named "ucontroller" which is attached to your serial port, you can send the commands by executing:

```
screen -S ucontroller -X readreg p /path/to/thefile
screen -S ucontroller -X paste p
```

## More resources

The information I have provided is taken directly from the [man pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) of [screen(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen). Here is the relevant part of the man page:

> readreg [-e encoding] [register [filename]]
>
> Does  one  of  two things, dependent on number of arguments: with zero
> or one arguments it it duplicates the paste buffer contents into the
> register specified or entered at the prompt.
>
> With two arguments it reads the contents of the named file into the
> register, just as  readbuf reads the screen-exchange file into the
> paste buffer.  You can tell screen the encoding of the file via the -e
> option.  The following example will paste the system's password file
> into the screen window (using register p, where a copy remains):
>
> C-a : readreg p /etc/passwd
>
> C-a : paste p